# Generating Symfony Form from generic data

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-forms

I am designing an application for managing reports. I'm developing this with Symfony 3.2.6 In this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wv1yH.png)  you can see my data model. I want to do two things:
1. Create new layouts for a report with a number of given modules
2. Create instances of this reports and save them in the database

So I think this is a way to do this with this data model, isn't it? But how can I now create a form in Symfony from that?

I do something like that:

```
$builder
        ->add('name', TextType::class)
    ;

    foreach ($options['moduleValues'] as $moduleValue)
    {
        if($moduleValue instanceof RangeModuleValue)
        {
            $builder->add('value', RangeType::class, array(
                'attr' => array(
                    'min' => $moduleValue->getRangeModule()->getStartValue(),
                    'max' => $moduleValue->getRangeModule()->getEndValue()
                )
            ));
        }
    }
```

But then I get the error:

```
Neither the property "value" nor one of the methods "getValue()", "value()", "isValue()", "hasValue()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "ReportBundle\Entity\Report".
```

I think the error is clear, the "value" is in the table range_module_value. But how should I change my design or my Form to handle this?

Note: the parent class Module exists, because there will be other modules like "TextModule" in future.

Here is my class Report:

```
class Report
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ReportBundle\Entity\ReportLayout")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="layout_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $layout;

/**
 * Report constructor.
 * @param int $id
 */
public function __construct($layout)
{
    $this->layout = $layout;
}


/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getLayout()
{
    return $this->layout;
}

/**
 * @param int $layout
 */
public function setLayout($layout)
{
    $this->layout = $layout;
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 *
 * @return Report
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}
```

}

And here is the class RangeModuleValue, in which I want to persist the value of a module for a specific report.

```
class RangeModuleValue
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ReportBundle\Entity\RangeModule")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="rangeModule_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $rangeModule;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ReportBundle\Entity\Report")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="report_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $report;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="value", type="integer")
 */
private $value;

/**
 * RangeModuleValue constructor.
 * @param $rangeModule
 * @param $report
 */
public function __construct($report, $rangeModule)
{
    $this->report = $report;
    $this->rangeModule = $rangeModule;
}


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set rangeModule
 *
 * @param string $rangeModule
 *
 * @return RangeModuleValue
 */
public function setRangeModule($rangeModule)
{
    $this->rangeModule = $rangeModule;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get rangeModule
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRangeModule()
{
    return $this->rangeModule;
}

/**
 * Set report
 *
 * @param string $report
 *
 * @return RangeModuleValue
 */
public function setReport($report)
{
    $this->report = $report;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get report
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getReport()
{
    return $this->report;
}

/**
 * Set value
 *
 * @param integer $value
 *
 * @return RangeModuleValue
 */
public function setValue($value)
{
    $this->value = $value;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get value
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getValue()
{
    return $this->value;
}
```

}

Comment: I guess you need to add a function addValue() to your entity . Can you add your entity (Class) to your post ?

Comment: Hi Melik, thanks for your edit. I added the report class and the rangeModuleValue class (there I want to persist the value). Should I edit my database design? Or is it possible with this design?

Answer (score 0):

In class report you add this function to allow add many `$rangeModule` or `$value` :

```
public function addrangemodule (RangeModuleValue $rangeModule)
    {
        $day->setIdReport($this);
        $this->ranges->add($day);
    }
```

But ranged should be an ArrayCollection :

```
 public function setranges(ArrayCollection $ranges)
    {
        $this->ranges= $ranges;
    }
```

In Controller adds as much as you need :
 $range = new RangeModuleValue();

```
    $report->addrangemodule ($range);
```

This code is just  an example i am not sure that he works.

For more information this is the documentation :

https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html

http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.3/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html

Comment: Thanks, but when I have more different module types. Should I generate a parent class ModuleValue and a 1:n relationshop to report?

Comment: I guess you need to use Association Mapping not inheritance . Take a look at this : http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html